# What is $P(x̃ > 72)$ given the following dist?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It can be shown that if $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ are $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $x̃$ is $N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$

Here we define $x̃=\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}$ (the average).

The question is:

If $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{25}$ are $N(65, \sigma^2 = 5^2)$, then find $P(x̃ > 72)$.

It is implied that all $x_i$ are iid (independently identically distributed).

---

How do I calculate this probability?

Would it be as follows:

$x̃$ is $N(65, 5^2/25)=N(65,1)$

Thus, $P(x̃ > 72) = 1 - P(x̃ \leq 72) = 1 - \phi(\frac{72-65}{1})=1-\phi(7)\approx 0$

where $\phi$ is how I calculate the probability using the CDF.

I don't think this is right though. If the mean is about $65$, then I do atleast except some $70+$ grades.

Comment: It looks right to me. The pdf of $\tilde x$ is more concentrated around the mean than $x_i$.

Comment: You've made everything completely right, but take care when $\sigma^2/n\neq 1$, then $$Z=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\Big(\tilde{x}-\mu\Big)$$ has a $N(0,1)$-distribution. The reason for that is $\mathbb{E}(aX+b)=a\mathbb{E}(X)+b$ and $\mathrm{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\mathrm{Var}(X)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $X_i$ is distributed as $X_i\sim \mathcal N(65,25)$. We can see at the graph how the pdf looks like:

[image]

It can be seen that $P(X_i> 72) \gg 0$

What is the variance of $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i$ are iid?

$Var\left( \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\frac1{n^2}\cdot Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \left( Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+\ldots + Var(X_n) \right)$

$=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \left(n\cdot Var(X_1) \right)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=\frac{25}{25}=1$. Therefore $\frac1{25}\sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i=\overline X_{25}\sim \mathcal{N}(65, 1)$

The graph of the pdf is

[image]

It can be seen that $P(\overline X_{25}> 72)\approx 0$.

The pdf of $\overline X_{25}$ is more concentrated around the mean than $X_i$. It confirms your result.

Comment: Thank you foir the graph, it helped alot!

Comment: @KSplitX You´re welcome. I´m glad that it helped.